# I have setup a filter but how do I clear the filter once finshed using it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Using Google worksheet apps-script and have been using filters in my script and now need to do some house cleaning and remove to filter once finished using it !

I set up the filter by doing the following

```
       var data = ws.getRange("B2:U" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();

       data = data.filter(function(r){ return r[19] == true });
```

Now that I have finished with the filter I would like to clear it!

Comment: Are you talking about a Google Sheets filter aand filter views or about the javascript function [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: Google-apps-script the script in Google worksheet I am kind of new to this but not new to programming in general

Answer (score 1):

The code included in the question shows the use of [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). This method doesn't require to be cleared as it doesn't make any change to the spreadsheet.